# Catch function is null error PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have this db Query in Laravel

```
Planning::max('Date')->select('Date')->get();
```

and I get this error message: Call to a member function select() on null!

How can I catch this error? When this error appears I need only a simple echo Information. When function select() is null then echo "This function is empty" or something like that.

Comment: use exception handling mechanism(try-catch) blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `Planning::max('Date')` is null, that means you might want to check the contents of your DB and make sure it is as populated as you think it is.

This will resolve your current problem, however:

```
$date = Planning::max('Date');
if(!$date) {
    print 'no date';
    return FALSE;
}
return $date->select('Date')->get();
```

Comment: `$date->select('Date')->get();` this will fail

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Planning::max('Date')` it will return a date or null if there are no data so in both case you can not do a select after, in fact you do not need to becouse you already have the data so:

```
$date = Planning::max('Date');
if($date)
    echo $date;
else
    echo "No data";
```